# Primefaces: Error al desplegar war en tomcat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, tomcat

Quiero desplegar mi war exportado en mi tomcat directamente y me sale este error (imagen). En el NetBeans funciona todo bien. Los pasos que hice en el Tomcat son: crear mi usuario, agregar al Path del sistema, Run al Tomcat, ingresar al localhost:8080, Manager App, seleccionar mi war y desplegar. Nada del otro mundo. Gracias por cualquier aporte válido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

¡Problema resuelto! Faltaba agregar este jar en la misma carpeta donde está Primefaces. 
https://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/start/1.0.10/

Y eso es todo. Aunque me queda como un misterio el porqué no le hace falta eso al IDE. Si alguien tiene el dato por favor compartir.